# Xen / libvirt - "End of file while reading data: Input/output error" when attempting to start a domain

Tags: xen, libvirt, opensuse

I'm getting the following string of errors when I attempt to start a domain using virsh:

```
virsh # start vimes
error: Failed to start domain vimes
error: End of file while reading data: Input/output error
error: Failed to reconnect to the hypervisor
```

Tailing the log files as this happen, I get the following output:

**/var/log/libvirt/libxl/vimes.log**

```
libxl: debug: libxl_create.c:1362:do_domain_create: ao 0x7f4e1c0017e0: create: how=(nil) callback=(nil) poller=0x7f4e1c0019c0
```

**dmesg**

```
[  852.559719] libvirtd[2187]: segfault at ffffffffffffffff ip 00007f4e45472614 sp 00007f4e3e6b60d8 error 7 in libc-2.19.so[7f4e453ed000+19e000]
```

**/var/log/libvirt/libxl/libxl-driver.log**

```
xc: debug: hypercall buffer: cache current size:4
xc: debug: hypercall buffer: cache hits:13 misses:4 toobig:1
xc: debug: hypercall buffer: total allocations:18 total releases:18
xc: debug: hypercall buffer: current allocations:0 maximum allocations:4
xc: debug: hypercall buffer: cache current size:4
xc: debug: hypercall buffer: cache hits:13 misses:4 toobig:1
xc: debug: hypercall buffer: total allocations:18 total releases:18
xc: debug: hypercall buffer: current allocations:0 maximum allocations:4
xc: debug: hypercall buffer: cache current size:4
xc: debug: hypercall buffer: cache hits:13 misses:4 toobig:1
```

I'm at a bit of a loss about how to proceed. It's not clear from the error messages what's actually going wrong. Host and guest are both running OpenSuse 13.2,

Comment: Edit `/etc/libvirt/libvirtd.conf` and change `log_level` to 1. Then reload libvirtd and try again. You should get a much more detailed and hopefully helpful log.

Comment: I've set that and restarted libvirtd, but it doesn't appear to have any affect on the output. I can get more output with 'LIBVIRT_DEBUG=1 virsh start vimes' though. I've put the dump from that up on Pastebin: http://pastebin.com/xYQV8n72

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to me, we are facing the same problem.

Please look at
Bugzilla – Bug 909547
https://bugzilla.opensuse.org/show_bug.cgi?id=909547

and temporary partial workaround (until host reboot !!)
described in opensuse forum
https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/502307-openSUSE-13-1-gt-13-2-upgrade-issues-with-xen-libvirt-and-virt-manager

Workaround:

1. As root make sure that there is nothing listed in the Virtual Machine Manager, and confirm there are no vm's running using `xl list` or `virsh list`.
2. Go to <kbd>Yast</kbd> > <kbd>Software</kbd> > <kbd>Software Management</kbd>, search for `libvirt`. Delete `libvirt`, `libvirt-daemon`, `libvirt-glib-1_0-0`, `libvirt-python`, and `perl-Sys-Virt`, when prompted with conflicts, use the first option to deinstall the conflicts.
3. Backup or delete `/usr/share/virt-manager`, and it's contents. (The folder will be recreated upon re-installation.)
4. Reboot using xen hypervisor, and login as root. (As a rule I have not been doing this using the desktop kernel)
5. Follow step 2 expect this time install the listed packages.
6. In <kbd>Yast</kbd> > <kbd>Virtualization</kbd> > <kbd>Install Hypervisor</kbd> and Tools tick only xen tools, then Ok.

   If at this point you would happen to reboot. It will break the system and you get the EOF error trying to install a virtual machine.
7. Go to the <kbd>Launcher</kbd> > <kbd>Applications</kbd> > <kbd>System</kbd> > <kbd>Virtualization</kbd> > <kbd>Virtual Machine Manager</kbd>. There should be nothing listed except the local host (xen).
8. Now you have two choices to installing a virtual machine by either clicking the "Create a new virtual machine" button which I believe uses `virt-install`, or clicking on the arrow next to the button, then clicking on `vm-install`. (I've been using the latter)

Comment: That sounds exactly like the issue I was having, although my eventual solution was just to set everything up using libvirt / KVM instead of libvirt / Xen.

Answer (score 0):

run vm-install --use-xl as root

Bug in 13.2. Read https://bugzilla.opensuse.org/show_bug.cgi?id=909547